# Please do I interprete this ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

Please if this function was to be converted to a "normal" if else statement, how would it look like?

```
export const orderArr = (arr: any[], key: string) => arr.sort((a, b) => ((a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : (a[key] === b[key]) ? ((a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : -1) : -1));
```

I want to add another condition, but I'm finding it hard to read or digest the current flow.

Comment: There is a code block, which is logically unreachable. Fix that also. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets expand the code to make it (slightly) easier to read.

*Note that the `?:` contains questionable logic, use of `===` seems to suggest it is trying to handle sorting an array of mixed types, but then using non-strict `<` and `>` comparisons. So for the purposes of the rest of this answer I am going to assume it is not trying to sort mixed typed arrays or that if it is, it will ignore strict type comparisons (ie the `===` should really be `==`)*

```js
function orderArr (arr: any[], key: string) {
  function sorter(a, b) {
    return (
      (a[key] > b[key]) 
      ? 1 
      : (a[key] === b[key]) 
        ? (
          (a[key] > b[key]) 
            ? 1 
            : -1
        ) 
        : -1
    );
  }
  return arr.sort(sorter);
}

export orderArr;
```

Now lets re-write the overcomplicated `?:` expression (overcomplicated not because of the `?:` syntax but because its doing more than it needs to) and rewrite as if then elses (note, this code is still wrong)

```js
function sorter(a, b) {
   if (a[key] > b[key]) {
     return 1;         // return 1 if a > b 
   } else {
     if (a[key] === b[key]) {        // questionable logic
       if (a[key] > b[key]) {        // questionable logic
         return 1;
       } else {
         return -1;      // will always return -1 (wrong, a == b should return 0)
       }
     } else {
       return -1;     // return -1 if a < b
         // or if type of a does not equal type of b (questionable)
     }
   }
}
```

Now lets simplify and fix the bug (ie remove the strict type comparison). Using a technique called early return (also called guard clauses), and avoiding using else as it adds unnecessary indentation and complication

```js
function sorter(a, b) {
   if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1;
   if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1;
   return 0;
}
```

Or if you prefer, using `?:` syntax

```js
function sorter(a, b) {
   return a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : a[key] < b[key] ? -1 : 0;
}
```

If you are sorting numbers, you can use a little trick to further simplify the code. Sort expects a `0` if `a` and `b` are equal, a negative value if `a < b` and a positive value if `a > b`, so for numeric sorting we can simply do

```js
function sorter(a, b) {
   return a[key] - b[key];
}
```

Now, lets put all the simplified code back together into a single line. First for any type of array.

```js
export const orderArr = (arr: any[], key: string) => arr.sort((a, b) => a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : a[key] < b[key] ? -1 : 0);
```

and for a numerical only array

```js
export const orderArr = (arr: any[], key: string) => arr.sort((a, b) => a[key] - b[key]);
```

Comment: *"Using a technique called early return, and avoiding using else as it adds unnecessary indentation and complication"* I guess that's entirely a matter of preference. Personally I usually find code easier to read if it relies on simple "if / else if / else" logic than if it relies on an "early return" trick.

Comment: @Stef I would encourage anyone reading to consider this programming style. Our company has adopted it and it makes code much simpler and easier to understand. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EumXak7TyQ0

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

According to @Erich Kitzmueller's answer, I removed *a[key] === b[key]* part:

```
export const orderArr = (arr: any[], key: string) => arr.sort((a, b) => 
{
    if(a[key] > b[key]){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
);
```

Original Answer:

I am not sure about sort function's structure but the if statement might look like below:

```
export const orderArr = (arr: any[], key: string) => arr.sort((a, b) => 
{
    if(a[key] > b[key] || a[key] === b[key]){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Actually, because the code in the original question probably does not what it is supposed to do, the if stratement should just read `if(a[key] > b[key]) {` because the equals part does fall back to -1, just like the else branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const orderArr = (arr: any[], key: string) => arr.sort((a, b) => ((a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : (a[key] === b[key]) ? ((a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : -1) : -1));
```

is equal to:

```
export const orderArr = (arr: any[], key: string) => {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[key] > b[key]) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a[key] === b[key]) {
            if (a[key] > b[key]) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    })
}
```

I'm strongly believe it's not necessary to use 3+ level nested ternary operators anywhere 'cause it's huge code readability sacrifice for no reason.

Feel free to rewrite method to common `if/else` or `switch` statements to keep your code clear.

Comment: In this, case, a large part of the whole expression is unreachable.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller Exactly. And it's much more easy to notice and fix in common style, then in "ternary nest"

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. You shouldn't nest ternary operators, thats bad practice.

For your case, not sure what type of data you're comparing. Examples: if it's number, you can use `a[key] - b[key]`. If it's string - `a[key].localeCompare(b[key])`

Answer (score 0):

Without any regards to logics, this is the if else version of the code:

```js
const orderArr = (arr, key) => {
  return (
    arr.sort( (a,b) => {
      if(a[key] > b[key]) {
        return 1
    }
    else if(a[key] === b[key]) {
        if (a[key] > b[key])
        return 1
        else return -1
    } else {
      return -1
    }
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***If-y version***

```
const iffyOrderArray =
  (arr: any[], key: string) => arr
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[key] > b[key]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        if (a[key] === b[key]) {
          if (a[key] > b[key]) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return -1;
          }
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      }
    });
```

---

***Original Version(Formatted)***

```
const orderArr =
  (arr: any[], key: string) => arr
    .sort((a, b) =>
    ((a[key] > b[key])
      ? 1
      : (a[key] === b[key])
        ? ((a[key] > b[key])
          ? 1
          : -1)
        : -1));
```

---

```js
const orderArr = (arr, key) => arr
  .sort((a, b) => ((a[key] > b[key]) ?
    1 :
    (a[key] === b[key]) ?
    ((a[key] > b[key]) ?
      1 :
      -1) :
    -1));

const iffyOrderArray = (arr, key) => arr
  .sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[key] > b[key]) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      if (a[key] === b[key]) {
        if (a[key] > b[key]) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    }
  });

const testArray = [{
  a: 42
}, {
  a: 21
}, {
  a: 23
}, {
  a: -45
}];

const testKey = "a";

console.log("Original", orderArr(testArray, testKey));

console.log("Revised", iffyOrderArray(testArray, testKey));
```

---

---

On Stackoverflow, ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***